# Inverted Corner Radius in WPF (something like a negative Radius)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

I try to create a border with a negative Corner radius, like this:

[image]

I want the radius on the inside. Is this possible with build in functions or do I have to paint it with a path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I faced the same problem and tried to figure out a solution.
Last but not least I came to the conclusion that it is not possible to solve this with a `border`.

I focussed on drawing my `Border` with the `Path` and the `CombinedGeometry` function.
If anyone is still looking for a solution how to make inverted round corners here is my solution:

```
<Grid>
            <Path Stroke="Black" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="10" Stretch="Fill">
                <Path.Data>
                    <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>                                
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="100,200 200,100"/>
                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="300,300" />
                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    </CombinedGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
    <Button Margin="10" Height="10" Width="10"/>
</Grid>
```

You can resize the `Rectangle`with changing the values in `RectangleGeometry Rect="100,200 200,100`and add inside it any other WPF item.. in this case I added a `Button`.

Here's the result:

[image: Result screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Border` in a `Border`

```
<Border Background="Black">
    <Border Margin="10" Background="White" CornerRadius="20">
        <!-- ... -->    
    </Border>
</Border>
```

[image]

Comment: That is not really what I want, the picture shows the complete border as it should look in the end.

Comment: Ok, it seems not to be the most elegant solution, but it works. I'm using two Borders now. They are not into each other but both well placed in a Grid.

Comment: This does answer does not solve the original problem. @Tokk if you have solved the original problem using a border within a border please do share how you did it.